# Provide start solution in MiniZinc

Tags: minizinc

How can one provide a start solution for an optimization problem formulated in MiniZinc in the IDE or via a data file to, e.g., speed up the solution process of the corresponding fd solver (in this case Gecode)?

Answer (score 1):

Constraint solvers, like Gecode, don't have a starting point. In short: they consider all possibilities and eliminate the ones that are non-solutions (propagation).

If you want to influence the way in which constraint solvers finds a solution, then the most similar way would be to influence the search strategy of the solver. In MiniZinc this can be done using search annotations: http://www.minizinc.org/doc-lib/doc-annotations-search.html

If you still want to use a starting solution, then local search might be more suitable for you application. There are local search solvers, like Oscar CBLS, that support MiniZinc/FlatZinc; however, in this case they work black box and you can not supply starting values for the variables. You would have to use direct calls to the solver to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. Actually, I was thinking of a way to impose an objective value bound other than directly restricting the corresponding objective value domain. This would have the side effect that the solution process always returns at least one solution.

Comment: It sounds like you are imposing a violation value to every possible solution and minimizing this value. This would be the general approach a local search solver would use.